# Clipboard in a loop and only get the Text first time

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop, clipboard

I have an Error and I don't get it. I am not getting an Exception.

I have to copy a text with the Robot.

```
// mark the text
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);


// robot copy the text
robot.keyPress((KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL));
robot.keyPress((KeyEvent.VK_C));
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyRelease((KeyEvent.VK_C));
robot.keyRelease((KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL));
```

then I get the Text via Clipboard

```
txt = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

After that, I want to set the text to the Clipboard, so I can put it in the text field again with the Robot.

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(txt);
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);


// robot mark the hole text
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);


// robot put the text in
robot.keyPress((KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL));
robot.keyPress((KeyEvent.VK_V));
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyRelease((KeyEvent.VK_V));
robot.keyRelease((KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL));
```

This is everything in a loop

```
 while (j < liUnderElementList.size()) {}
```

The first time it works as expected but on the second pass, I get the first copied text and not the new text.
BUT in my Clipboard is the new Text.

If i wait with

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2)
```

nothing changes.

Anyone can help me?

I would be very thankfull.

Comment: instead of sharing parts of your code withe "then","after that" try to share minimal reproducible example please, then people viewing your question could reporduce the  same problem and provide you some answers.

Comment: I tried to reproducible my code by myslef. So i did it so: I have 5 editors open with different textes and I made an loop. I click manually in the first editor then the code copy, edit and paste the Text und then i clicked in the second editor window and so on. But i worked! But i don't know the difference. I copy & paste it from my "normal" Code. The only difference is, that one is in editor and one is on a website and with selenium to click to the next website.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with the order of keys, in the way you are performing. Release event should be from last one. Use below one:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.delay(1000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: thanks but that is not the problem because it work fine in the first round in the loop